# How can I find ".dat" within all *.mk files?

Tags: awk, grep, find

I am trying to grep for the `.dat` string in all my `*.mk` files using the below command. I am wondering if this is right, because it doesn't give me any output.

```
find . -name "*.mk" | grep *.dat
```

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2013/01/search-string-in-multiple-files.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not right, there are a couple of issues: 1) you seem to be supplying grep with a glob pattern, 2) the pattern is not quoted and will be expanded by the shell before grep ever sees it, 3) you're grep'ing through filenames, not file contents.

To address 1), use Basic Regular Expression, the equivalent here would be `.*\.dat` or just `.dat`. 2) is a matter of using single or double-quotes. 3) `find` returns filenames, so if you want grep to operate on each of those files either use the `-exec` flag for `find` or use `xargs`. All these taken together:

```
find . -name '*.mk' | xargs grep '.dat'
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Use Find's Exec Flag

You don't really need a pipeline here, and can bypass the need for *xargs*. Use the following invocation to perform a fixed-string search (which is generally faster than a regex match) on each file found by the standard *find* command:

```
find . -name '*.mk' -exec grep -F .dat {} \;
```

If you're using GNU find, you can use this syntax instead to avoid the process overhead of multiple calls to grep:

```
find . -name '*.mk' -exec grep -F .dat {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Use xargs:

```
find . -name "*.mk"| xargs grep '\.dat'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using exec option in find command this way:

```
find . -name "*.mk" -exec grep ".dat" \{\} \;
```